# How to change global variables and pass them to a function's parameters with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, global-variables

I am trying to pass two variables to a pre-written function that has 2 parameters.  The idea is when a users clicks on a filter variable 1 gets set, then when they click on an item variable 2 gets set.  Once they click on an item it sets the two variables as the parameters in a pre-written function (I cannot gain access to change this function).  Here is what I have.

HTML Filters:

```
<a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current filter">All</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".filter1" class="filter">filter1</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".filter2" class="filter">filter2</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".filter3" class="filter">filter3</a>
```

HTML Links:

```
 <a data-track="Track Var Link1" href="link1.aspx">Link 1</a>
 <a data-track="Track Var Link2" href="link2.aspx">Link 2</a>
 <a data-track="Track Var Link3" href="link3.aspx">Link 3</a>
```

jQ:

```
var filterText = 'all';
var trackText = '';

$('a.filter').click(function(event) {
    filterText = $(this).data('filter');
});

$('.item a').click(function(event) {
    trackText = $(this).data('track');
});

$('.item a').click({param1: filterText, param2: trackText}, preWrittenFunction);
```

Pre-Written-Function:

```
function preWrittenFunction(type, lname) {
    s = s_gi(s_account);
    s.linkTrackVars = 'prop5,prop17,prop18,pageName'
    s.linkTrackEvents = 'None';
    s.prop5 = document.URL.toLowerCase(); // url
    s.prop17 = s.pageName; // name and campaign pathing
    s.prop18 = type; // widget type
    s.tl(this, 'o', type + ": " + lname); // link name includes type
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the call to your `preWrittenFunction` in an anonymous function to be used as `click` event handler:

```
$('.item a').click(function() {
  preWrittenFunction(filterText, trackText);
});
```

Comment: Yep - worked.  Sometimes it's the small mistakes that get you :] Thanks for the extra eyes.